# POST are being sent as GET in nativescript/angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm building a nativescript app with Angular, but my http request are ALL being sent with GET although I identify as POST. As the result the backend is rejecting me the request.

Here you have my post code:

```
_post(url: string, params?: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<Response>((resolve, reject) => {
      const res = new Response();
      request({
        url: this.endpoint + url,
        headers: { Cookie: this.authService.getCookie() },
        content: JSON.stringify(params),
        method: "POST"
      }).then((response: HttpResponse) => {
          try {
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
              if (response && response.content) {
                res.failed(response.content.toString());
              } else {
                res.failed("Usuario no autorizado");
              }
            } else {
              res.wasSuccess(response.content.toJSON());
            }
          } catch (error) {
            res.failed("Usuario no autorizado");
          }
          resolve(res);
      }, (e) => {
        res.failed("ERROR");
        resolve(res);
      });
  });
  }
```

But when I cheked the debug

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apart from that `request` is deprecated, the documentation says the `method` parameter should be of type `RequestMethod`, not a plain string … https://angular.io/api/http/Request

Comment: Good point... I take this from nativescript documentation (this is my first nativescript app) https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http
So I should install the @angular/common/http in my app so I can use that?

Comment: Well if you have no requirement to make it work using deprecated functionality (existing environment demanding it), then I’d rather start with what is current, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Using Angular + Nativescript I would definitely recommend injecting the angular http module into your component and then using it to make your http calls.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class APIService {
    path: string = "http://some_server_url:3000/route/";

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

    someMethodName(id: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.path + id).toPromise().then(response => {
            if (response)
                return response;
            else
                return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [HttpClient](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/http) api. If you still face issues, please share the Playground example.

Answer (score 0):

Check httpClient of Angular https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient.

This is an example of HttpClient working on Angular: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/httprequest

I'd suggest you follow this path.